# Выводится мусор в функции

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор

Есть перегруженный переменными double конструктор CCoord, также есть функция f_Print(), которая служит для вывода в терминал в функции main. Проблема: выводится мусор.

```
class CCoord {
public:
double x, y, h, x2, y2, h2;
public:
CCoord(double x, double y, double h, double x2, double y2, double h2){  // Конструктор задает 2 пеленгатора 
    x = x;
    y = y;
    h = h;
    x2 = x2;
    y2 = y2; 
    h2 = h2;
}
void f_Print() { 
    cout << "x: " << x << endl;
    cout << "y: " << y << endl;
    cout << "h: " << h << endl;
    cout << "x2: " << x2 << endl;
    cout << "y2: " << y2 << endl;
    cout << "h2: " << h2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что в выражении `x = x;` переменная `x` слева от оператора присваивания — это член класса `CCoord`, а не параметр конструктора?

Comment: Мне нужны эти поля класса и перегруженный конструктор, не знаю как нужно записать

Comment: 1) Использовать разные имена. Например, `x_m = x;`, или `x = x_;`, или ещё как-нибудь. 2) Использовать указатель `this`: `this->x = x;`.

Comment: Помогло, пугает что сам не додумался

Comment: По-хорошему инициализацию полей класса следует проводить в списке инициализации: `) : x{x}, y{y} ...` а тело конструктора оставить пустым

Answer (score 1):

Этот фокус — с одинаковыми именами — работает при *инициализации*, т.е.

```
CCoord(double x, double y, double h, double x2, double y2, double h2)
{ 
    x = x;
    y = y;
    h = h;
    x2 = x2;
    y2 = y2; 
    h2 = h2;
}
```

полная ерунда (присвоение аргументов самим себе), а

```
CCoord(double x, double y, double h, double x2, double y2, double h2)
:x(x), y(y), h(h), x2(x2), y2(y2), h2(h2) {}
```

вполне корректный вызов, где члены класса инициализируются переданными в конструктор параметрами.